# Using Blazor Modal and Authentication State

Tags: .net, modal-dialog, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to use [Blazored.Modal](https://github.com/Blazored/Modal) with [AuthenticationState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component-1).

I can't find any documents that shows how to combine these two attributes/keys in the App.Razor file.

Below is how I currently have my App.Razor:

```
 <CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="@lazyLoadedAssemblies" OnNavigateAsync="@OnNavigateAsync">
        <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
.
.
.
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I need to insert `<CascadingBlazoredModal>` somewhere but I have no clue. I've tried adding it below but that seems to create two renders of the page. I tried wrapping the above code with CascadingBlazoredModal, I tried putting CascadingBlazoredModal inside the AuthenticationState.

The only docs I see are around CascadingValues/Params but that's not what I'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! Not sure if it's the best option but...

I had to wrap the `CascadingBlazoredModal` around the `Authenticationstate`... AND add authenticationstate within the `Found`...

If I don't wrap the whole `Router` with the `AuthenticationState` I wouldn't be able to access the whole app but just the page I authenticated myself with (sigh)..

```
<CascadingBlazoredModal> 
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="@lazyLoadedAssemblies" OnNavigateAsync="@OnNavigateAsync">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <CascadingAuthenticationState>
                    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                </CascadingAuthenticationState>
            </Found>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Excellent.  It all depends on how `CascadingBlazoredModal` works.  I have my own (simpler modal) so don't use it, and therefore haven't dug through the source code.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I'm now seriously considering creating my own modal as I'm hitting a limitation... I want the parent page to listen to an eventcallback from the referenced component in the modal dialog to close the dialog but can't seem to pass in a function (which closes the modal dialog) as a parameter.  I might have to create another question around it. haha.

Comment: If you're stuck ask it as a question.  There is an answer using events.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested this, but from the docs this should work:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
  <CascadingBlazoredModal>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
        ...
    </Router>
 </CascadingBlazoredModal>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

You should be able to pick up the cascaded value in your modal hosted forms.

```
[CascadingParameter] public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthTask { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I definitely tried adding the cascadingblazoredmodal inside the authentication state. 

I actually got it to working, tho! I had to use some creative license. Combined your idea and the official docs Idea.

I'll update the post :)